# Paperclip and S3 storage seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I've setup my Rails 4 app to use S3 storage over Paperclip gem. Upload of files is working perfectly through create method, images are show using `= image_tag(@listing.avatar.url)`...
The problem I have is when I use `seed_dump` and create the seed.db; reset the database and seed the data again the paths to S3 where the images are not correct anymore?!

**application.rb**

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

**listing.rb**

```
has_attached_file :avatar
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Long story short: how do you dump your data and seed it back again without losing the avatar URL?